# Django model - field_id is None, even though field is not None, getting an error as a result

Tags: django, django-models

I'm getting an error I don't understand with Django 1.3 about an object member being null. That member isn't a field, it is the id for a field.

Here's the code.

**The model:**

```
class DirectorsIndividual(models.Model):
     company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyUK)
     director = models.ForeignKey(Director)
     individual = models.ForeignKey(Individual)
```

**The error:**

```
IntegrityError: mainapp_directorsindividual.director_id may not be NULL
```

**The code that creates the object**:

```
link = DirectorsIndividual(company = co,
                           individual = individual,
                           director = officer)
```

**The state of the object** (irrelevant fields omitted):

```
link.director => <Director: Director object>
link.director_id => None
link.director.id => 3
link.individual => <Individual: Individual object>
link.individual.id => 2
```

What's happening here? Why is the DirectorsIndividual object not picking up the id of the director object assigned to it?

[**Edit:** more object info]

Comment: Are you sure that the variable `individual` actually refers to anything?

Comment: The correct way to handle this issue is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932006/django-deferring-save-of-graph-of-model-objects-transactionally-create-models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the order in which you are assigning and saving the objects.  Here's a super-reduced example:

```
from django.db import models

class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Y(models.Model):
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
```

This will cause the integrity violation:

```
x = X()
y = Y()

x.name = 'test'
y.x = x # At this moment, the pk has not yet been assigned.

x.save() # Assigns the pk, but doesn't copy it over to the foreign key in y.
y.save() # Bang.
```

Comment: Yep, this is it. Is there a recommended pattern for creating a graph of objects, then saving it all after the graph has been created?

Comment: I generally go with a "save early and often" approach, saving each new object as soon as it is created. Of corurse, this will not help circular dependencies, but a circular FK relationship is pretty uncommon.